# App with tail Command?

Tags: applications

Is there an app that will let me run the UNIX tail command?

I want to be able to monitor a text file on a remote web server as it gets written to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the syntax, but Terminal Emulator on my Samsung Galaxy S lets me run `tail`.  I would assume any console app would allow it.

As noted in the comments below, `tail` is part of BusyBox so you can get it from there.  There is [a root app on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox)  that includes BusyBox if you don't want to search for a package to sideload.

Comment: When I run tail in Terminal Emulator on my Galaxy S it says 'tail: not found' :-/

Comment: @Techboy Hmm. Are you rooted? It's possible that tail could be part of Busybox.  Or maybe it's my custom ROM or my specific variant of the SGS (T-Mo Vibrant). I'm not sure.

Comment: I checked, it is part of Busybox, so you need to be rooted...

Comment: I'm not rooted - but I might do that... Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to be rooted. Busybox should work without root, but you'll need to call the busybox `tail` explicitly, e.g. by `/sdcard/busybox tail`.

Comment: The BusyBox description explicitly says it needs root - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwic3Rlcmljc29uLmJ1c3lib3giXQ

Comment: @studgeek That app needs root, and some BusyBox utilities might need root (situationally), but `tail` does not require root to access apart from if you want to use it on protected files.  As liori mentions you can just stick the version of `tail` compiled for Android somewhere accessible and run it.